# Factoring trinomials by grouping and problems with getting the s

Tags: factoring

*Factor by grouping the trinomial:*
$6x^2+x −1$

**a)**
$6x^2+ 3x  −2x  −1$
$3x(2x + 1) + 1(−2x − 1)$
$(3x + 1)  (−2x− 1)$

**b)**
$3x(2x+1)−1(2x+1)$
$(3x − 1)(2x+1)$

Beginner in Algebra and I have a question on factoring by grouping trinomials, especially concerning the last parentheses, the subtraction/negative signs especially. I am getting things wrong on a regular basis and would like some advice. I'll try and state as clearly as I can. Also, and not really part of the question I guess but can't you group these in any way and still get the same answer? Or no?

But for the question. For the part labeled **a)**, specifically $+ 1(−2x − 1)$ If done this way it gives me the opposite of the answer. *Or does it?* Or am I getting the signs mixed up and not remembering certain math rules in order to get this right?

For example, in part **b**, I can get the correct answer if I switch the signs and make the 1 a $-1$ and the other two values, $2x + 1$. But am I allowed to do that? It feels like I shouldn't have the freedom to just change those signs w/o somehow factoring them out in some way. Or am I making it too hard and this is possible?

[factoring trinomials by grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF4zF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the distributive property, $ab+ac=a(b+c)$.  For part b, $-1(2x+1)=-1(2x)+-1(1)=-2x-1$.  Now that each addend has a common factor of $2x+1$, you can combine like terms, which is again using the distributive property.$a=2x+1,b=3x$, and $c=-1$.

For part a, does $c=2x+1$ or $-2x-1$?  You cannot combine like terms as written.  You could do $-3x(-2x-1)+1(-2x-1)$ in which case you have $c=-2x-1$.  Combining like terms then yields $(-3x+1)(-2x-1).$  The third line in part a does not follow from the second.  Try substituting $x=1$.

Comment: Thank you! It's much clearer. After a good nights rest, looking over my notes and your comment. For part **a**, I now see I was trying to factor out a positive 1, which didn't exist, there was no positive 1 there. But there was a negative one to factor out ($c = -1$). At least I think I'm on the right path thinking this. Thanks again!

Comment: @xr4d11 That's not quite it.  The first line to the second line is valid.  The only question is what are you factoring from each half of the sum.  In part b, the common factor was $2x+1$.  In part a, what was the common factor?  If you were factoring out $-2x-1$, the first term should have been $-3x(-2x-1)$.